# ArchLinux + nginx + Passenger Rails app always pointing to localhost

Tags: nginx, passenger, archlinux

This is my first time using `Arch` based `Linux` environment (Manjaro Linux), and also `Nginx`.

I installed Nginx, opened `http://localhost` and it showed the standard `Welcome to Nginx` page.

Then I created 2 folders:

- /etc/nginx/sites-available
- etc/nginx/sites-enabled

In `sites-available`, I created a conf file named `iima`, with following data:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name iima.merged.localhost;
  passenger_enabled on;
  location / {
    root /home/path/redacted/public;
  }
}
```

and then created a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/iima /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/iima
```

Then in the `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`, I added:

```
include       /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

In the `/etc/hosts`, I added the following line at the end of the file:

```
127.0.0.1       iima.merged.localhost   iima.merged.localhost

# I also tried below line while removing above line
127.0.0.1       iima.merged.localhost
```

Restarted the nginx server using `sudo systemctl restart nginx` (also tried with `reload`), but typing `iima.merged.localhost` always points to localhost page.

Am I missing anything? There are no `error(s).log` created in `/var/log/nginx`.

EDIT:

Content of `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/harsh/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.45;
    passenger_ruby /home/harsh/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/bin/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    include       /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Comment: Did you install nginx with passenger? By default nginx don`t have directive `passenger_enabled`. And show you /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and other files from /etc/nginx/sites-available/ (if they exist).

Comment: @mr_tron, I added the `nginx.conf` to the post. I have alerady added the content of a single file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`.

Comment: For creating error.log uncomment `error_log  logs/error.log;`. But i don`t understand why you see default_page. Config is valid. Maybe file mode or owner for /etc/nginx/sites-available/iima and /etc/nginx/nginx.conf are different?

Comment: @mr_tron, File modes for `nginx.conf`, `/etc/hosts` and `sites-available/iima` are all `644` i.e. RW-R-R and owner are all root-root.